# Write a Graph into a file in an adjacency list form [mentioning all neighbors of each node in each line]

Tags: python, networkx, writefile, undirected-graph

I need to write a graph in a text file where each line of the file is composed from one node followed by all its neighbors. It's basically what an [Adjacency List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) is, and what the function `write_adjlist` is supposed to do. Unfortunatly it's not the case, as the edge are not replicated. In the exemple of wikipedia the adjacency list is :

> a     adjacent to     b, c
>
> b     adjacent to     a, c
>
> c     adjacent to     a, b

We can see that all edges are present two times (the edge `(a,b)` in lines 1 and 2, the edge `(b,c)` in lines 2 and 3...).

But now if I use the following code to generate a small world network :

```
import networkx as nx

N=5  #Number of nodes
v=2  #Number of neighbours
p=.1 #rewiring proba

G = nx.connected_watts_strogatz_graph(N,v,p)
nx.write_adjlist(G.to_undirected(),"test.txt")
```

it gives me :

```
#adj.py
# GMT Thu Jan 21 06:57:29 2016
# watts_strogatz_graph(5,2,0.1)
0 1 4
1 2
2 3
3 4
4
```

where I would like to have

```
0 1 4
1 2 0
2 3 1
3 2 4 
4 0 3
```

Do you know how I could do to have the output I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is how the `write_adjlist` is defined so in order to have the file written as you want a simple work around can be done with the following function:

```
def adj_list_to_file(G,file_name):
    f = open('tst.txt', "w")
    for n in G.nodes():
        f.write(str(n) + ' ')
        for neighbor in G.neighbors(n):
            f.write(str(neighbor) + ' ')
        f.write('\n')

N=5  #Number of nodes
v=2  #Number of neighbours
p=.1 #rewiring proba
G = nx.connected_watts_strogatz_graph(N,v,p)
nx.draw(G, with_labels= True)
plt.show()
adj_list_to_file(G.to_undirected(),"tst.txt")
```

The file output is:

```
0 1 4 
1 0 2 
2 1 3 
3 2 4 
4 0 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just wonder why not implement a function that actually do what it is supposed to do?

Comment: i think it is done that way to avoid redundancy, especially when the graph is much larger. That is for instance in the first line it says the `node 0` has neighbors `1 and 4`, then when you come to `node 1` there is no need to say that `node 0` is a neighbor because you already said it.

Comment: Hm yes, I can see, they prefered avoid redundancy than keeping to the definition :)